# Activate a cell-range on SelectionChange via keyboard input

Tags: excel, keyboard-events, selectionchanged, vba

I activate a given cell range on a worksheet by means of the following excel-vba code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
' msgbox("Change recognized")
If Sh.Name <> "Spielfeld" Then
    If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
        Dim UserSelection As Range
        Set UserSelection = Sh.Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(16, ActiveCell.Column))
        UserSelection.Activate
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The code works fine when changing the column / cell via mouse input. But if I just press the left or right arrow key, excel changes the active cell / active column **without** selecting the defined UserSelection! Nevertheless the sub itselfs is always activated when pressing the arrow keys (a msgbox will popup even if I change the cells via the arrow keys). 
Can anyone tell me why my selection is not automatically updateded when changing the column with the arrow keys? How can I do this?

Comment: The down arrow is working, but left/right/up is making the selection default to row 1.  I'm also noticing that if you click on Row 1 anywhere it's not working.

Comment: I'm noticing that using Shift+Arrow works (most of the time, and timing matters).

Comment: This is happening for some reason because of the Row being 1.  It is very strange, because I'm handling the case that it is Row 1, and then just setting the range manually, trying to use UserSelection, and checking it's address is correct, but when trying to activate that range, if it came at all from a Row1 Target, it's not having it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **Select** rather than **Activate**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Sh.Name <> "Spielfeld" Then
    If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
        Dim UserSelection As Range
        Set UserSelection = Sh.Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(16, ActiveCell.Column))
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            UserSelection.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why does it refuse incoming ranges using Row 1 specifically, including clicking on a cell in Row1?

Comment: @p  On my system **Column 1** is not affected.  This is correct.  *Arrow* keys allow the selected block to move right or left. *Enter* and *Tab* keys allow selection to change **within** the selected block.

Comment: Your solution is perfect.  I was asking in general, why the OP's code works in all cases except when the input target.address originates from row 1.  The Arrow keys will take the selected block, since it starts at say $B$1:$B$16 and then much like a merged cell defaults to the lowest part, the address if you RIGHT from B1:B16, would go to C1.  So the incoming target.address is row 1, and then his code would not work.  I can see there's a difference in Select and Activate, and understand the difference, but not enough to get why his worked for every row but Row 1.

Comment: @peege  There are very subtle differences between **Select** and **Activate.**  I confess I do not fully understand these differences.  When navigating **within** a worksheet, I always use **Select** rather than **Activate.**